# How to Convert JsonApiSerializerSettings and JsonOutputFormatter to .Net Core 3.0

Tags: serialization, deserialization, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, jsonapi-serialize

Hi Im current changing out a solution from targetting .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.0. The .Net Core2.2 soultion has the JsonApiSerializerSettings and JsonOutputFormatter setup as below.

```
  var jsonApiSerializerSettings = new JsonApiSerializerSettings
    {
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };


var jsonApiOutputFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(jsonApiSerializerSettings,ArrayPool<char>.Shared);
jsonApiOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
jsonApiOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/vnd.api+json");
```

How can i accomplish the same in Core 3.0?